# CoreData MagicalSave crash

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a very simple method for creating an object.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSInteger dayID = [[[self periodFormatter] stringFromDate:today] integerValue];

CDDay *dDay = [CDDay MR_createInContext:localContext];

dDay.dayID = @(dayID);

[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

This is all it does, it works with all my unit tests, stress test and automation tests on iPhone 3,4 and 5 but when hitting the App Store when 100k+ users install it I get around 500 crashes from this method.

I tried both in the main thread and a background thread, same problem. It only takes a few ms and it's only being called once.

Here is the log from the thread that crashes

```
1    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 5
2    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 172
3    libobjc.A.dylib     (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 356
4    CoreFoundation  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
5    Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 120
6    CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 942
7    ******  __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke3 (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.m:64)
8    CoreData    developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 86
```

I know MR's been having some problems with nested contexts but this is with the default context. Feels like I have to get rid of MR.

Comment: This looks like a problem in CoreData's save: method.

Comment: Did you maybe found solution to your own problem? I'm facing the same issue here.

Comment: Sadly enough, nothing..